# Existe algún algoritmo para determinar si un rectángulo esta dentro de otro

Tags: java, lógica

Realmente no se como saber si un rectangulo esta dentro de otro he probado con este algorito
Primeramente el problema se repite una cantidad de veces (NC)numeros de casos donde me pide calcular el area real de los rectangulos ingresados
En el progama creo una clase rectangulo con 4 parametros x,y,x1,y1 que son las cordenadas de los dos puntos que necesito para calcular el rectangulo
luego creo un vector de rectangulo donde almaceno los rectangulos ingresados luego en la varibale res se calcula el resultado
Aqui un ejemplo de un caso de prueba (GRAFICADO)
[image: EL RESULTADO DEBERIA ARROJAR 3O DE AREA REAL]

el codigo que utilize es este
public class RECTANGULO {

```
static Vector<Rectangulo> rectangulos= new Vector<Rectangulo>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);
    int casos=lee.nextInt();

    for(int a=0;a<casos;a++) {
        //LLENAMOS CON LOS VECTORES
        int n=lee.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            Rectangulo aux=new Rectangulo(lee.nextInt(),lee.nextInt(),lee.nextInt(),lee.nextInt());
            rectangulos.add(aux);
            //System.out.println("El triangulo nro:"+i+"tiene como coordenadas"+rectangulos.elementAt(i).x+","+rectangulos.elementAt(i).y+" "+rectangulos.elementAt(i).x1+","+rectangulos.elementAt(i).y1); 

        }
        int resultado=area(0);
        //
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
            if(EstaDentro(i,i+1)) {
                //System.out.println("el triangulo"+i+"esta dentro del triangulo"+i+1);
                int aux=rectangulos.elementAt(i).x1-rectangulos.elementAt(i+1).x;
                int aux2=rectangulos.elementAt(i).y1-rectangulos.elementAt(i+1).y;
                int aux3=aux2*aux;
                resultado+=area(i+1)-aux3;

            }else {
                System.out.println("el triangulo"+i+1+"NO esta dentro del triangulo"+i);
                resultado+=area(i+1);
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Caso#");
        System.out.println(resultado);
        rectangulos.clear();
    }

}
static boolean EstaDentro(int anterior,int nuevo) {
    int xn=rectangulos.elementAt(nuevo).x;
    int x1=rectangulos.elementAt(anterior).x1;
    int yn=rectangulos.elementAt(nuevo).y;
    int y1=rectangulos.elementAt(anterior).y1;

     // SOLO DETERMINAMOS SI ESTA DENTRO NO POR CUANTO
    if((xn<x1)&&(yn<y1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//sacamos el area
static int area(int indice) {
    int x=rectangulos.elementAt(indice).x1-rectangulos.elementAt(indice).x;
    int y=rectangulos.elementAt(indice).y1-rectangulos.elementAt(indice).y;
    return  x*y;
}
```

}

```
class Rectangulo {
int x,y,x1,y1,dx,dy;
Rectangulo(int x,int y,int x1,int y1){
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.x1=x1;
   this.y1=y1;
   dx=x1-x;
   dy=y1-y;
}
//Creamos clase para almacenar rectangulo
```

}

Comment: Amigo este código que expones ¿tiene algún fallo?, presenta algún error?

Comment: Te aconsejo primero resolverlo con lápiz y papel, luego cuando ya sepas cómo se resuelve crea un código. Si haces código antes de entender la solución de un problema solo estás perdiendo el tiempo.

Comment: Excelente consejo Lobos!

Comment: @ZeroHour07 Hint: usa la formula de distancia entre 2 puntos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi consejo es que establezcas los 4 puntos de las esquinas del rectángulo contenedor con sus coordenadas x e y. Las cuales son x,x+width, y,y+height

Si otro cuadrado/rectángulo está en su interior, significa que sus 4 esquinas están contenidas en las anteriores.

Si se cumple:

x_interior>x_exterior&&x_interior< x_exterior+width_exterior

significa que el primer punto está dentro de la altura del rectángulo contenedor(exterior)

Si se cumple:

y_interior>yexterior&&y_interior< y_exterior+height_exterior

significa que el primer punto está dentro de la anchura del rectángulo contenedor (exterior)

Si se cumplen las 2 condiciones a la vez, ese punto con su x e y está dentro del rectángulo.

Otra opción es usar la clase Rectangle de java.awt y sus método contains, el cual, en su interior, hace exactamente todo lo anterior:

```
java.awt.Rectangle miRectangulo=new java.awt.Rectangle(1,1,4,4);
System.out.println(miRectangulo.contains(new java.awt.Rectangle(2,2,1,1)));
```

Este código te dará en pantalla un true

Comment: gracias un abrazo